# Expressions like <<1>>

Tags: warning-messages

In a function where I call the `Maximize` function, I am getting an error that says

```
"The function value -0.956338\ (Abs[<<1>>]^3+Abs[0.918621 (<<1>>)+<<19>> (<<1>>)]^3)^(1/3) is not a number at {x$16906[1.],x$16906[2.]} = {0.9186212148724066`,0.7166887533790196`}"
```

What does the expression <<1>> mean?

Comment: That probably you should read manual page for Skeleton function :)

Comment: Try `RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 100] // Short` and see.